# C Pointer Write Error

Tags: c, pointers

```
 void fileNameProcess(char * inputName){
             int size =strlen(inputName);
             bool change=false;
             char * name=inputName;

             for(int i =0; i<size; i++){
                 char temp=* (name+i);
                 if(temp<0x10||temp>0x5b){
                     change=true;
                 }else if(0x19<temp<0x21){
                     change=true;
                 }else if(0x3a<temp<0x41){
                     change=true;
                 }
                 if(change){
                     //*(name+i)='_';
                     memset(name+i, '_', 1);
                     change=false;
                 }
             }

         }
```

it breaks when i try to set a character in a string (memeset), but i dont understand why it doesnt allow me to do that? why i can allow access to read it but couldnt modify it?
can anyone explain it in memory aspect. i guess it is because the string is passed into the function. but as long as i know the memeory location, i could set it right?

thanks

```
char * filename= strdup("try1.mat");
    writter.locate(filename);
```

in locate it assign filename to class memeber char* filepath

Comment: If you're passing a const string in inputName then you'll be trying to modify read-only memory. You should also have seen a compiler warning when you did this. One small additional point: why are you using memset to modify a single char - why not just `name[i] = '_';` ?

Comment: You may also be passing an invalid pointer. Is that a const char*, or else how was it created?

Comment: Your code also lacks some other insight. Why do you do these confusing things in the first place? No need of your `temp`. Use just `name[i]` everywhere. And using `memset` to assign a character in a string is ... do as Paul indicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
if(1 < variable < 2)
```

Probably doesn't do what you want. Use:

```
if(1 < variable && variable < 2)
```

**edit**
if(1 < variable < 2) evaluates like this:

```
if( (1 < variable) < 2)
if( (true) < 2)
//given true is often* assigned a value of 1 this will always be true and
if( (false) < 2)
//false is always zero this will also be true
```

*I don't think this is required by the standard so don't rely on it.

Comment: can you expian why if(1 < variable && variable < 2) doesnt work?

Comment: The result of the `<` operator is in fact defined to be either 0 or 1 - you *can* rely on it.

Comment: and in C99 `true` is defined to be 1, also

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you are giving a constant literal string as the input:

```
char * str = "test";
fileNameProcess(str);
```

If that is the case, try:

```
char * str = strdup("test");
fileNameProcess(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you're passing in a string literal to the function:

```
fileNameProcess( "myfile.dat");
```

String literals cannot be modified.

However, you could pass in an array that's initialized by a literal:

```
char fname[] = "myfile.dat";

fileNameProcess( fname);
```

As with any string handling routines, take care that when you modify the passed in string that you keep it properly terminated and don't write past the end of the buffer.